# SOAP: Add user and password to the soap:address location URL doesn't work?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

When I curl this **url**,  It works :

```
curl http://OLM:OLM794%24@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080
```

But, when I call it in my soap address like this, it doesn't work :

```
<soap:address location="http://OLM:OLM794%24@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080/"/>
```

It shows me : `(SoapFault): Authorization Required`

Have you an idea why ?

#### Update:

`sw.xml`

```
....
<wsdl:service name="Toto">
        <wsdl:port name="GazListeImpayesHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="tns:TotoSoap11Binding">
            <soap:address location="http://OLM:OLM794%24@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080/web/services/Toto.TotoHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Then in my file that calls that soap:

`file.php`

```
<?php
$soap = new SoapClient('http://domaine.com/sw.xml');

var_dump($soap->__getFunctions()); //OK
var_dump($soap->__getTypes()); //OK

$result = $soap->__soapCall("method", array("parameters"=>array("args0"=>array("NUM"=> "123"))));
var_dump($result);
?>
```

**result:**

```
(SoapFault): Authorization Required
```

Comment: That soap:address looks like a part of your WSDL, are you sure that is actually the endpoint you call with your WebService call? Maybe you can show the code where you make the SOAP call, and show the actual message that is being sent?

Comment: @ophychius you can see my update...

Comment: I found the solution, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, the user and password should be added in the SoapClient method and not directly in wsdl `soap:address location`

like this:

```
$user = "your user here";
$password = "your password here";
$url = "path of wsdl location here";
$credentials = array(
    'login' => $user,
    'password' => $password,
);

$soap = new SoapClient($url, $credentials);
```